# Iterating through collection - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing an online ecommerce for the first time and currently, i am not able to iterate through my collection.

Every item for a shop is categorized into a product category. My relationship is below

**Category**

```
public function items()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item','category_item','category_id','item_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
  }
```

**Items**

```
public function categories()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category','category_item','item_id','category_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
 }
```

This code here is able to fetch the groups and their products. I try to loop through to get the names of the products like below but it only displays the name of the last product in the database.

Why is this happening?

**ItemController**

//get id of product categories and display all products in grid table

```
$items_in_table = Category::whereIn('id',$request->get('product_category'))->with('products')->get();
foreach($items_in_table as $item)
 {
   return $item->name;
 }
```

**update**

```
 $temp
  foreach($items_in_table as $item)
  {
   temp = $item;
  }
```

return $temp

**response**

{"id":2,"title":"freight","no_of_contacts":0,"user_id":1,"created_at":"2018-04-15 23:55:30","updated_at":"2018-04-15 23:55:30","**items**":[{"id":1,"name":"AirBag ","phone":"0247878234","group_id":null,"user_id":1,"created_at":"2018-04-16 00:14:20","updated_at":"2018-04-16 05:31:05","pivot":{"group_id":2,"customer_id":1,"created_at":"2018-04-16 05:33:08","updated_at":"2018-04-16 05:33:08"}}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr40P.png)

Comment: You must return a view with the view name you wish to render and which variables should the view use, smth like: `return view('products.list',[products=>$items_in_table]);` Do you need a JSON response or a rendered template response because from your code there is no way to tell, furthermore it breaks at the first item because of the `return` statement which is expected

Comment: @ka_lin, i don't need a rendered template response. I need to fetch the names of the items displayed from each group

Comment: Make a temp variable and append to it in the foreach and return the temp variable

Comment: @ka_lin please look at my update and my json response. I have higlighted item in there.. I am trying to reach that and display the name

Comment: Deleted my answer, basically it's what `Amr Aly` said ... ish..., it is not clear what you are trying to achieve:1. You want to return a json 2.You stated "and display all products in grid table"...you need to send `$items_in_table` to a view and make 2 foreach to render them

Comment: I am not rendering template response because i don't need the data at frontend. I do need the data at the server side for processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's define our relationships first

**Category**:

```
public function items()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item')
            ->withTimestamps();
  }
```

**Item**:

```
public function categories()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')
        ->withTimestamps();
 }
```

then in your controller:

```
$items_in_table = Category::with('items')->get();
$names = [];
foreach($items_in_table as $category) {
  foreach($category->items as $item) {
   $names[] = $item->name;
  }
}

dd($names);
```

Comment: I am getting an empty array. can't tell why

Comment: could you please `dd($items_in_table);`

Comment: i checked it but it still not clear what data in that variable is

Comment: but when i return $items_in_table, it is not empty

Comment: I know that, I need your response structure so i will try to guide you extract the data you want

Comment: i have replaced a new image. i hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to put it in an array and then rotate it

```
$items_in_table = Category::whereIn('id',$request->get('product_category'))->with('products')->get();

$name = [];

foreach($items_in_table as $item)
{
  $name[] = $item->name;
}

return $name;
```

Comment: i am getting [null,null] and i am new to laravel. Don't understand the error

Comment: @JonathanFeud please show here the output function dd($items_in_table)

Answer (score 0):

foreach will not manipulate the values of the array

Some possible solutions:

1. [Use a reference](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), this will change the values in $items_in_table

   `foreach($items_in_table as &$item)
   {
       $item = $item->name;
   }`
2. [Use map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map) (since it is an Laravel-collection), this will also alter the array

   `$items_in_table->map(function ($item) {
       return $item->name;
   })`

Answer (score 0):

you can Access any relation like this way .

> For View what is you are getting. you can also use `dd($item->quoteReturnDetail)`

```
 return collect($models->items())->transform(function ($item, $index){
        if( $item->quoteReturnDetail){  dd($item->quoteReturnDetail);  }   });
```